# hosting .net 4.0 REST WCF service in IIS 6

Tags: c#, wcf, iis-6, .net-4.0

So i am on VS2010 running iis 7 with .net 4.0

I have a REST wcf 4.0/.net 4.0 services that runs locally very beautifully. On my local it is  hosted on IIS at

http://localhost/SOMENAME/

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Ping")]
    public string CheckAuthenticatedStatus()
    {
        string userName;
        if (!AuthenticateUser(out userName))
        {
            WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return "Authenticaltion Failed";
        }
        return "Ping Back - " + userName;


    }

    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "AnonymousPing")]
    public string CheckStatus()
    {

        return "AnonymousPing Back";

    }
```

But when i try to deploy it in QA environment (win2k3 .net 4 iis 6) I get the following error.

Directory Listing Denied
This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

How do i go about this? And I don't need a SVC file on my local to run the web service.
All the online help (courtesy of google)  talk about the SVC file. 
Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally found what I was looking for.

Step 1) VirtualDirectoryName->Properties->Virtual Directory Tab->Confirguration Button->

Insert new WildCard Mapping C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll Uncheck Verify that file exists

Step 2)

VirtualDirectoryName->Properties->Directory Security Tab->Authentication and access control->Edit Button->

Uncheck Integrated Windodws Authentication

Step3) Reset IIS

The following two links helped me out!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/2ec269e3-c1ff-4d9b-9ff3-d530f1599047

http://forums.asp.net/t/1195663.aspx

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to document this. I was pulling my hair out  with this same problem until I came across your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post about WCF RESTfull service hosting on IIS6. 
[wcf-restfull-service-on-iis6-and-consuming-by-jquery](http://deepasp.wordpress.com/2014/07/18/wcf-restfull-service-on-iis6-and-consuming-by-jquery/)