# When I publish a WCF rest service in IIS the services do not work?

Tags: wcf, rest, .net-2.0, .net-4.0, .net-1.0

Im using WCF REST **4.0** meaning to say their is no .svc file.. So I have 3 different service classes in one service WCF Rest Application project. And I registered all these services in the Global.asax

What im trying to do is that I have a set of Business Functions from a lower framework e.g: .NET 1.0/2.0 where in i use datasets and not call basic add/update/delete entity function unlike in the newer releases. So I wanted to ask if this type of match would work in .Net 4.0 or is their any other reason for this?

Thank you

Comment: I'm having a similar issue and have not found a solution as of yet.  Mine is interesting in that there are two methods in my service (Init and Search).  I can get one of them to work (Init) but the other (Search) always returns the basic error message of: "Request Error The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your services work in Web Development server than they have to work in IIS. What version of IIS do you use? Remember that extensionless URLs are only supported in IIS 7.x. If you want to use them in older version you have to modify IIS configuration (check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367457/hosting-net-4-0-rest-wcf-service-in-iis-6)). Also make sure that your IIS has properly registred .NET 4.0 and all realted ISAPI. If you installed .NET 4.0 after IIS it is best to use aspnet_regiis.exe from .NET 4.0 folder.

Comment: I am using IIS 6.0. I tried the steps but I wasnt able to follow because I published through Visual Studio and the process is completely different Let me tell you the step by step process I follow below:
1) Right click service then click publish
2) publish Method File System
3) Target Location --> http://localhost/CustomerService

Then in IIS I configure the ff:
1) Enable Directory browsing
2) Advance settings-->Application Pool= ASP.NET v 4.0
3) Edit Permission of Service Then Security then add Network Service

Then when I check my Service
http://localhost/CustomerService/CustomerService/help

Comment: I get the error:

Request Error

The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.