# Unable to host WCF REST Service 40(CS) on IIS 7

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, iis-7, service

I have created WCF REST service in vs2010(4.0) with WCF REST Service Template 40(CS). It works fine on localhost and local IIS (7.5), without giving me any errors. But while I am trying to deploy it on server, it gives me 500 Internal server error. I have deployed same way I did on locl IIS. It is not giving me more details about the error. When I checked the server log, it says service.svc - file does not exist. While I have not created .svc file, I did directly with given template.

Can any one please help me to find the solution to this...

Thanks in advance...

---

I am using template, so there is no .svc file. In this we can directly access the uri without .svc with the filename.

---

Chrome is just displaying me 500 Internal server error. It is not displaying any related information about error.

-

Satyen Pandya

Comment: Can you browse to the .svc file in IIS manager?

Comment: In order to help you, we need the full error message with a stack trace. Try to access the WCF REST service from your browser. If the internal error occurs as well, it should show a mainly yellow page with all details about the error. If the yellow part is missing, put <customErrors mode="Off"/> into your web.config file.

Comment: If Chrome doesn't display any related information about the error, then add <customErrors mode="Off"/> to the <system.web> part of web.config and try again. It's unlikely anybody can help you without more detailed information about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the thing that causes error in my service. I have used MySQL database and for that reference to MySql.Data.dll file of older version, and when I upgraded that dll with newer version, my entire project was not responding. It was replaced my newer version and when I tested with older version, service is running fine.

**And for hosting it on WCF, Normal procedure of hosting the site on IIS worked for me after  solving above problem...** And I better opt for going with .net 3.5 WCF Rest Service with .svc extension available.

Thanks all for reviewing my problem..

Take a look at similar post...
@ [hosting .net 4.0 REST WCF service in IIS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3367457/hosting-net-4-0-rest-wcf-service-in-iis-6)